# How Do I Seed My Database in the setupBeforeClass Method in a Laravel 4 Unit Test?

Tags: database, testing, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 test class with some tests for which I want to seed my database before running the tests.  Using the setup() function to reseed for each test takes far too long.  However, when I try seeding in the static setupBeforeClass() function or the constructor, I obviously can't use the $this->seed() method.

But neither can I use programmatic Artisan commands, because when I do, I get the following error:  `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Artisan' not found in <test class name>.`

Here is the code I'd like to use to seed:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
Artisan::call('db:seed', array('--class'=>'TestSeeder');
```

Please let me know how I can seed my database once per test *class* rather than per test *case*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An "improvised" but pretty clean imho way to achieve a similar effect would be to do this in `setUp`, but have it run *only once* (similar to what `setupBeforeClass` does) like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    protected static $db_inited = false;

    protected static function initDB()
    {
        echo "\n---initDB---\n"; // proof it only runs once per test TestCase class
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        // ...more db init stuff, like seeding etc.
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        if (!static::$db_inited) {
            static::$db_inited = true;
            static::initDB();
        }
    }

    // ...tests go here...
}
```

...this is my solution and it seems simple enough and works fine, solving the performance problems of seeding and rebuilding the db structure before every test run. But remember, the *"right" way to do testing*, that gives you the greatest confidence your tests methods don't get subtly interdependent in bug-hiding ways, is to re-seed your db before every test method, so just put seeding code in plain `setUp` if you can afford the performance penalty (for my test cases, I couldn't afford it, but ymmv...).

Comment: How do you handle resetting the database once all the tests are done?

Comment: You can use DatabaseTransaction trait and then db will be the same before every test method.

Comment: @melihovv That will not work since the DB is created inside of the transaction. After the first test, the database creation is undone, and the static attribute prevents it from being recreated.

Comment: Perhaps this is outdated... you should use the official setUpBeforeClass and tearDownAfterClass PHPUnit API that @Taskeen Fatima's mentioned in their answer

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved with this

```
passthru('cd ' . __DIR__ . '/../.. & php artisan migrate:refresh & db:seed --class=TestSeeder');
```

Comment: yes! you have know idea how long I searched for an answer like this!

Comment: this is not fully working, because testing normally is using sqlite in memory.

Answer (score 5):

This is so far the best solution I found

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
/**
 * This method is called before
 * any test of TestCase class executed
 * @return void
 */
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    parent::setUpBeforeClass();
    print "\nSETTING UP DATABASE\n";
    shell_exec('php artisan migrate --seed');
}

/**
 * This method is called after
 * all tests of TestCase class executed
 * @return void
 */
public static function tearDownAfterClass()
{
    shell_exec('php artisan migrate:reset');
    print "\nDESTROYED DATABASE\n";
    parent::tearDownAfterClass();
}
/** tests goes here **/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Laravel 5,6,7,8,9
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing

```
use RefreshDatabase;
```

Outdated:

> This trait is a wonderful way of resetting the database
>
> ```
> <?php
> namespace Tests;
>
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
>
> trait MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce
> {
>     /**
>      * If true, setup has run at least once.
>      * @var boolean
>      */
>     protected static $setUpHasRunOnce = false;
>
>     /**
>      * After the first run of setUp "migrate:fresh --seed"
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function setUp() : void
>     {
>         parent::setUp();
>         if (!static::$setUpHasRunOnce) {
>             Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');
>             Artisan::call(
>                 'db:seed',
>                 ['--class' => 'CompleteTestDbSeeder'] //add your seed class
>             );
>             static::$setUpHasRunOnce = true;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Unattributed copy from here: https://medium.com/helpspace/fresh-database-once-befor-testing-starts-faa2b10dc76f

Comment: it was from GitHub somewhere, but glad u found an article on medium.

Comment: For me, the first test passes, second test "General error: 1 no such table: users". So the database tables are not retained between tests.

Comment: Don't use this... just use `use RefreshDatabase;`...

Comment: I don't think so.  See @Taskeen Fatima's answer, and use official setUpBeforeClass and tearDownAfterClass PHPUnit API

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing So yeah phpunit does offer a setup before and after method which is commonly used to do this type of thing. That includes you adding the connection and commands tho. laravel has it's own trait called Refreshdatabase @94638857

Answer (score 0):

You can do now:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->seed();
}
```

in your `setUp()` method for your test.

The `seed()` method accepts as a parameter the seeder class.

```
public function seed($class = 'DatabaseSeeder')
{
    $this->artisan('db:seed', ['--class' => $class]);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10 you don't need the `setUpBeforeClass` method for this. Instead you can use the `RefreshDatabase` trait. Before running the first test, it will rollback and re-run all the migrations and, if in the test class the `$seed = true` property is specified, will run the seeders. In addition, each test will be executed inside a transaction. For example:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\CreatesApplication;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, RefreshDatabase;

    protected $seed = true;

    public function test_something(): void
    {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

See for details [Running Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database-testing#running-seeders) section and source code of the [RefreshDatabase](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/RefreshDatabase.php) trait.