# How to Run Laravel Database Seeder from PHPUnit Test setUp?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-seeding

I am trying to recreate the database before each test in some PHPUnit test cases. I am using Laravel 5.3. Here is TestCase:

```php
class CourseTypesTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'TestDatabaseSeeder ', '--database' => 'testing']);
    }

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_list_course_types()
    {
        $httpRequest = $this->json('GET', '/api/course-types');
        $httpRequest->assertResponseOk();
        $httpRequest->seeJson();

    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

Running `phpunit` fails with error:

> $ phpunit PHPUnit 5.7.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> E                                                                  1 /
>   1 (100%)
>
> Time: 2.19 seconds, Memory: 12.00MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) CourseTypesTest::test_list_course_types ReflectionException: Class
>   TestDatabaseSeeder  does not exist
>
> D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:749
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:644
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:709
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php:74
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php:63
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:2292
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php:64
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:508
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:169
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:254
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:155
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:821
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:187
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:118
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:107
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:218
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:237
>   D:\www\learn-laravel\my-folder-api\tests\rest\CourseTypesTest.php:17
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

but this class exists:
[image: TestDatabaseSeeder inside database/seeds]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is empty space in your --class argument. If you take close look at array `'--class' => 'TestDatabaseSeeder '` there is space in the end ... this is the problem. Change it to `'--class' => 'TestDatabaseSeeder'` and it should work fine.

Comment: Congrat! 
Empty space .. great :)

Comment: If you like migrate only one time your data, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893698/how-do-i-seed-my-database-in-the-setupbeforeclass-method-in-a-laravel-4-unit-tes

Answer (score 38):

Since version 5.8 you can do:

```
// Run the DatabaseSeeder...
$this->seed();

// Run a single seeder...
$this->seed(OrderStatusesTableSeeder::class);
```

[Take a look at the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#using-seeds)

Comment: How to run multiple seeder? Just multiple single call or I can pass an array to $this->seed()?

Answer (score 22):

The `DatabaseSeeder` can be instantiated on its own, and its `call` method is public.

All you need to do in your `CourseTypesTest` class would be

```
(new DatabaseSeeder())->call(TestDatabaseSeeder::class);
```

Or you can make use of Laravel's `app` helper as follow

```
app(DatabaseSeeder::class)->call(TestDatabaseSeeder::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your database with `Artisan`:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:fresh --seed');
```

*This command removes your tables, creates the tables again (runs the migrations) and then seeds the tables with clean data.*

Answer (score -3):

[image]

You can try this way. You can execute this command when you run your test.

Comment: Please include the source code in the answer body instead of using an image.