# Retaining a sqlite database for multiple tests in Laravel/phpunit to reduce time taken

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

I have a lot of tests and running all of them takes a long time ~15 minutes. This is mainly due to a lot fo the tests building a new sqlite database and seeding it.

A lot of my tests don't change the database, so they could all be run on the same database, which is created just once. However, I can't figure out how to setup my tests to work like this.

I use an in memory sqlite, in Laravel.

I am trying to stop my phpunit tests from creating and seeding the database every time.

My latest attempt is to use the trait detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57788123/42106

However, when I run my tests, the first test passes fine (so the database tables exist) then the 2nd test in the file fails with: "General error: 1 no such table: users".

```
./bin/phpunit ./tests/Auth/UserTest.php
```

So the database tables have been wiped after the first test.

I have tried overriding the tearDown method but it makes no difference.

What could be wiping my database?

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Auth;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Tests\MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce;
use App\Entity\Models\User;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    use MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce;

    public function testUser1()
    {
        $user = User::where('id', 1)->get()->first();
        $this->assertTrue($user->id !== null);
    }

    public function testUser2()
    {
        $user = User::where('id', 2)->get()->first();
        $this->assertTrue($user->id !== null);
    }
}
```

Here is the trait:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

trait MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce
{

    /**
     * If true, setup has run at least once.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected static $setUpHasRunOnce = false;

    /**
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        if (!static::$setUpHasRunOnce) {

            echo '--DB--';
            Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');

            Artisan::call(
                'db:seed',
                ['--class' => 'DatabaseSeeder'] //add your seed class
            );

            static::$setUpHasRunOnce = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my TestCase class:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected $baseUrl = 'http://dev.php73.mysite.com:8888';
}
```

My phpunit env vars:

```
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing" />
    </php>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the default configuration (i.e. if you uncommented [these lines](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/phpunit.xml#L25)) the default sqlite test database is an in memory database so it would be wiped between tests.

Comment: Yes, I want to have it in memory and persist between tests. Is that possible?

Comment: as far as I know each test is run in its own PHP process so there's no memory sharing possible

Comment: Why won't you use `use RefreshDatabase;` trait? Why do you need to persist the data in memory/sharing?

Comment: Just want it to run quickly. I have hundreds of tests so there’s no need to create, seed and destroy the full database every time

Comment: Not a direct solution, but have you tried using file storage for sql lite, you may find that unless the database is large that the cache will do a lot of the work for you.

Comment: I'm just gonna make a guess,  maybe you need to run "'db:seed'" on every test case run  but prevent 'migrate-refresh'

Answer (score -1):

as @matiaslauriti stated in the comments, with Laravel 8, you should use the RefreshDatabase trait. Once applied it will look for a boolean property called `seed`.

Give your test class the protected property `$seed` and set it to true if you wish to seed and move tests that don't need a refresh to another test class.

```
class ProjectControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $seed = true;
}
```

Then only seed necessary tests will build the database.

Alternatively use:

```
$this->seed();
```

inside a test method, to seed for the specific test.

check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#running-seeders) on it

Comment: This will help if there are seeders involved, but what they're looking to avoid is the database rebuild with each test. This will still run `migrate:fresh` for every test.

Answer (score -2):

You're almost there believe it or not...

Change the name of the setUp() method in your MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce trait to `setUpOnce()` like so...

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

trait MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce
{

    /**
     * If true, setup has run at least once.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected static $setUpHasRunOnce = false;

    /**
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUpOnce() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        if (!static::$setUpHasRunOnce) {
```

You just need to implement the setUp method on each test case class (which does the magic with the trait) like so...

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Auth;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Tests\MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce;
use App\Entity\Models\User;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    use MigrateFreshAndSeedOnce;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {

        $this->setUpOnce();

    }

    public function testUser1()
    {
        $user = User::where('id', 1)->get()->first();
        $this->assertTrue($user->id !== null);
    }

    public function testUser2()
    {
        $user = User::where('id', 2)->get()->first();
        $this->assertTrue($user->id !== null);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add that manually to every test case class, perhaps you could add it to your `abstract class TestCase` and it might apply automagically to all test case classes?

Comment: Where is `setUpOnce()` defined? What do you think it should do?

Comment: Sorry, good catch - answer updated.

Comment: And it means that we will call the setUpOnce method from the trait (where the magic happens) as opposed to the one in the BaseTestClass

Comment: That’s not how inheritance works. If you define a `setup()` method in the child class it overrides the one in the parent class.

Comment: OP. Just give it a try. Trust me, it works.

Comment: I can’t believe the downvotes on this… it’s actually working